# NODE-SOAP error handling

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, soap-client, node-soap

I'm consuming a SOAP WS in  http://{{URL}}/web/wsGlbSSL.asmx?WSDL
The function is GetResultSQL and it needs parameters.

when i do this using a Google Chrome App for example, the call goes perfectly passing:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:br="http://URL/br/">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <br:GetResultSQL>
        <br:codUsuario>BLA</br:codUsuario>
        <br:senha>BLABLA</br:senha>
        <br:codColigada>0</br:codColigada>
        <br:codAplicacao>V</br:codAplicacao>
        <br:codSentenca>BLABLI</br:codSentenca>
        <br:xmlParamsValue><![CDATA[<PARAM><EMAIL>teste@email.com</EMAIL></PARAM>]]></br:xmlParamsValue>
        <br:schema>false</br:schema>
    </br:GetResultSQL>
</x:Body>
```

but with node js node-soap i can't make it work

```
var url = 'http://{{URL}}/web/wsGlbSSL.asmx?WSDL';
var args = {
codUsuario: "BLA"
,senha : "BLABLA"
,codColigada: "0"
,codAplicacao: "V"
,codSentenca: "BLABLI"
,xmlParamsValue: "<![CDATA[<PARAM><EMAIL>teste@email.com</EMAIL></PARAM>]]>"
,schema: "false"
};
soap.createClient(url, args, function(err, client) {
    if(err){ 
        console.log(err);
        console.log('########## Erro ao criar cliente ##########');
        return;
    }
    client.GetResultSQL(args, function(err, result) {
        if(err){ 
            console.log(err); //this is always thrown
            console.log('########## Erro ao consumir servico ##########');
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

It gives me the same error as if i pass something wrong on parameters by the chrome app. "Fail to convert XML to object DATASET".

Comment: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/pull/787/files

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out what was it.
Soap-node won't support CDATA so i edited it to proccess my CDATA.